# How to know if your code is executed on wordpress.com and wordpress.org?

Tags: plugins, wordpress.com-hosting

You can now install 3rd party plugins and themes on wordpress.com with the business plan.

I wonder if there is any way to know if the plugin or theme is ran on a self-hosted wordpress site or if it's hosted on wordpress.com.

```
if (is_selfhosted()) {
    //
} else {
    //
}
```

I checked `$wp_version` global variable but it just shows that your run the latest version.

Is there any specific constant for instance?

Last thing, if I use this type of variable, will my plugin still pass validation on the wordpress plugin directory?

Comment: why not to simply ask wordpress.com support? in any case if you are using different code for different hosts you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: I agree it's usually a good indicator that something is wrong but I believe there are valid use for this. About asking support, it's a pretty good idea!

Comment: you are doubling the effort testing the plugin and to test on wordpress.com you will have to have a business account, and you are unlikely to be able to run unit tests therefor only manual tests for you... there must be a great amount of $$$ involved in order to go that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to identify a custom plugin or combination of plugin found on wordpress.com (check the code of https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-plugins/) and defined if you are self-hosted or not.